# 2dstrings and strncmp

Tags: c

After i input 10 names ,I have to print all the names that start from A .its not printing anything

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
void main(void)
{
    int i;
    char names[10][50];
    printf("Enter 10 names:\n");
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter name %d\n",i+1);
        gets(names[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        if(!(strncmp(names[i],"A",1)))
        {
        printf("%s",&names[i]);
        }
    }
getch();
}
```

Comment: Your code looks like it works to me - a quick test here confirms that.

Comment: i entered both starting from A and not starting from a..wait a second i didnt used capital a sorry :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me:

```
Enter 10 name
Enter name 1
jon
Enter name 2
andy
Enter name 3
Andy
Enter name 4
bob
Enter name 5
dave
Enter name 6
fred
Enter name 7
jim
Enter name 8
sarah
Enter name 9
alex
Enter name 10
richard
Andy
```

The last line there is the matching 'Andy'. Note that this is case sensitive so `andy` doesn't work whereas `Andy` does

Answer (score 1):

Aside from a couple of nits (see below), the code looks fine.  Personally, I'd change

```
if(!(strncmp(names[i],"A",1)))
```

to

```
if(names[i][0] == 'A')
```

or, even better

```
if(tolower(names[i][0]) == 'a') // case-insensitive test; make sure ctype.h
                                // has been #included
```

Nits:

**NEVER NEVER NEVER NEVER NEVER** use `gets()`; it is unsafe and creates a security hole that is easily exploited by malware.

Change

```
gets(names[i]);
```

to

```
fgets(names[i], sizeof names[i], stdin);
```

and pretend you never heard of `gets()`.

Also, make sure that your compiler documentation explicitly says that "void main(void)" is a valid signature; not all compilers support it (the standard signatures for `main` are either `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)`).

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work fine.  If you're having a problem it might be because you don't flush the output buffer.  Adding `\n` to the `printf()` line should do it.  Or explicitly call `fflush()` if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

The code works as expected. Check your input.